# How to convert a Pose to PyKDL Frame in python (and vice versa)

Tags: ros, ros2, pose, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1 I used `tf_conversions.posemath`, `toMsg` and `fromMsg`.  I'm porting my code to ROS2 and I can't seem to find the Python3 module `tf_conversions`.  If the module existing, what is the debian package to install (Ubuntu 20.04/Galactic)?  If not, is there a different module/API available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393894/how-to-convert-a-pose-to-pykdl-frame-in-python-(and-vice-versa)/) by [anton.deguet](https://answers.ros.org/users/52067/anton.deguet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`toMsg` and `fromMsg` were not ported to ROS 2. Refer to this discussion:

https://github.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/commit/93009e916ffafbd07e183efd2829101c4c2bd88e

You can use:

```
void tf2::convert(const A & a, B & b)
```

https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/tf2/html/namespacetf2.html#af1255c37833c838543b512febce5e9b1

`convert()` function converts any type to any type (messages or not). Matching toMsg and from Msg conversion functions need to exist. If they don't exist or do not apply (for example, if your two classes are ROS messages), just write a specialization of the function.

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2022-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0